# xamarin.forms german resx (language) ignored on android, working on ios

Tags: android, forms, xamarin

I am making an app with support for english, german and arabic.
The user can change the app language at runtime on click.

```
switch (v)
            {
                case "german":
                    mainPage.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
                    LocalizationResourceManager.Instance.SetCulture(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("DE"));
                    CachedUser.localCode = "de";
                    break;
                case "arabic":
                    mainPage.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
                    LocalizationResourceManager.Instance.SetCulture(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ar"));
                    CachedUser.localCode = "ar";
                    break;
                case "english":
                    LocalizationResourceManager.Instance.SetCulture(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en"));
                    mainPage.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
                    CachedUser.localCode = "en";
                    break;
                    
            }
```

There a three resx files

[image]

All are identicaly, only the strings content ofc changes depending on the language.

This is the german resx file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <resheader name="resmimetype">
        <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="version">
        <value>2.0</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="reader">
        <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="writer">
        <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
    </resheader>

        <data name="YouAreHere" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Du befindest dich hier: </value>
    </data>

        <data name="Next" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>weiter</value>
    </data>

    <data name="German" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Deutsch</value>
    </data>

    <data name="Arabic" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Arabisch</value>
    </data>

    <data name="English" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Englisch</value>
    </data>

    <data name="PickLanguage" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Wähle deine Sprache</value>
    </data>

</root>
```

This, for instance, is the working arabic one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <resheader name="resmimetype">
        <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="version">
        <value>2.0</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="reader">
        <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="writer">
        <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
    </resheader>

        <data name="YouAreHere" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>أنت هنا: </value>
    </data>

    <data name="Next" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>التالي</value>
    </data>

    <data name="German" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>ألمانية</value>
    </data>

    <data name="Arabic" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>عربي</value>
    </data>

    <data name="English" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>إنجليزي</value>
    </data>

    <data name="PickLanguage" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>اختر لغتك</value>
    </data>

</root>
```

You can see, they all are identical.
The code works perfecly on iOS.
But on Android, the german language is ignored. Between Arabic and english I can switch perfectly.

What  could be of issue here?

Comment: If it is convinient for you, could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Yes, i did https://innomotionmediagmbh-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/j_tolksdorf_innomotion-media_com/EvX1e0aj1DNBrHYhUEH1J1MBrEvKd-c7FqeIOK4Ep-q35w?e=WOunSj

Comment: Yes, it is just the case as you said . I am trying to involve someone familiar with this topic to further look at this issue. There might be some time delay. Appreciate your patience.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT thank you very much. im looking forward to updaes! :-)